# Why three assets directory generated in rails 3.1 and higher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, assets

Can anyone explain what the use of the following directories is?

- `app/assets/`
- `lib/assets/`
- `vendor/assets/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These directories are all a part of *Rails' Asset Pipeline*.

Conceptually, the `app/assets` directory is for your application assets (for instance, the stylesheets and images for your application). `lib/assets` is for all of the code that you've written that stands alone from your rails app (javascript library, maybe). `vendor/assets` is meant to house all third party libraries (e.g. jQuery).

All of these paths are included by default in the asset pipeline. This means that their contents can be included into other files using sprockets, concatenating automatically into one file (javascript or css), reducing the number of requests and thus the loading time. The asset pipeline can also compile your coffeescript and minify your javascript for production.